# Visual Studio 2015 breakpoint condition for two dimensional vector size

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, visual-studio-2015, conditional-breakpoint

I have a two dimensional vector at which I want to break if the height does not equal the width.
I thought of a condition like this `my_vector.size() != my_vector[0].size()` but when I tried this I got the error "This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated".
I saw the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620614/c-debugging-by-visual-studio-watchpoint-on-vector-size-change) question and tried to use `_Mylast` and `_Myfirst` but then I got the error "The breakpoint cannot be set. a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function".
What else can I do to get the size of a vector in a breakpoint condition?

Comment: Instead of a conditional breakpoint (which are quite slow, so this trick also works for code run in tight loop), just insert an if statement in the code: `if (my_vector.size() != my_vector[0].size()) { __debugbreak(); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question hasn't received a more elaborate answer yet, I'll post my comment as an answer.

Instead of trying to use a condition breakpoint, you can modify the source code, to call into the debugger itself:

```
if (my_vector.size() != my_vector[0].size())
{
    __debugbreak();
}
```

This is also useful for a tight loop, because a conditional breakpoint is very slow, whereas this technique has minimal overhead.